# Multiple diagonal background color

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to have a background drawable like below picture.
How should I create it?
[image]

Comment: create a custom `Shape` class, override its `draw` method and pass it to a `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extends target `Drawable` class(maybe `ColorDrawable`). Then draw a trapezoid `Path` in `draw(Canvas)` methods. Adjust `Paint`'s alpha and color to change the effect. Code may like bellow:

```
public class SDrawable extends ColorDrawable {

    private Path mPath = new Path();
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public SDrawable() {
        init();
    }

    public SDrawable(int color) {
        super(color);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        mPaint.setColor(0x33ffffff);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0,0);
        mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()/2+50, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight());
        mPath.lineTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
        mPath.lineTo(0, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

}
```

Comment: while the result would be ok but i dont like your inheritance hierarchy (extending `ColorDrawable`), i think that extending `Drawable` would be better (but, yes, more code) or creating a custom `Shape` and passing it to `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Comment: Or maybe you can extends the background's host `View`, and apply the logic I have said above, of which the key point is to `draw a trapezoid shape` beyond everything drawn.

Comment: no, no, no, your first solution is good: a custom `Drawable`, not a custom `View`

Comment: But the second can deal with all kinds of `Drawable` which is simpler. Anyway, choose as you prefer.

Comment: so you want a custom `ImageView`, a custom `Spinner` a custom `SeekBar` a custom .... or just one custom `Drawable` that can be used with `View#setBackground()`?

Comment: Just extends the `View` that you invoke `setBackground()` from. This View is where your `Drawable` will be drawn to.

Comment: i mean i want that background in `ImageView`, `Spinner`, `SeekBar` and maybe 10 other types of views

Comment: Oh, if that, extending `Drawable` will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use below `drawable` XML in your layout Background , Change color in below `drawable` XML according your application need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/application_background"
                android:endColor="@color/bright_red"
                android:angle="45"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

See Below Link for how you can change and use above code .

http://www.singhajit.com/gradient-color-in-android/

Comment: I don't want gradient. please see picture. It should has border

Comment: means you want border in diagonal .